# Strange jQuery Unrecognized Expression (Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a really weird bug in jQuery 1.11.1 (Compressed).

I have a collapsing div and when I load the page page I am developing on my Mac the I can get this to work perfectly. Thinking the page was ready to be finalised I did a test on good old Windows and it was not working.

I had a look at the console to see why this isn't working and I was presented with the following error"

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: . jquery.js:2
```

So I decided I would look further into what was happening with this error and this is what the console output also displayed upon further inspection.

```
fb.error jquery.js:2
fb.tokenize jquery.js:2
fb.select jquery.js:2
fb jquery.js:2
m.fn.extend.find jquery.js:2
m.fn.init jquery.js:2
m jquery.js:2
```

I'm not 100% is there is an issue with this particular version of jQuery or if it is something I am doing.

Here is the code for my collapsing dive.

```
$('.').click(function(){
    $('.round-details')
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as this issue is a bit beyond my abilities with jQuery as I am still only learning.

Thanks

Stu :)

Comment: what is this..? `$('.')`

Comment: `Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
 throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
};`

That is the code block that is throwing the error.

Comment: All I did was download this from jquery.com, I have not edited it.

Comment: @StuartCowley: Right. The problem isn't in what you downloaded. It's in the code you've quoted for your "collapsing dive" [sic].

Comment: I had the same error and it was due to my Wordpress-Bootstrap Navbar had a anchor tag URL inside it that couldn't be understood.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to select with the "." selector?

See the selectors documentation : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Beside that, you should use the uncompressed version of jQuery when trying to debug.

Comment: I have no idea, as I have mentioned above all I did was download the compressed version. It worked perfectly on OS X and then I get on a Windows machine and this error is thrown. I then went and downloaded the uncompressed version to see what the deal was and where the issue was.

Maybe if I tried an earlier version... As mentioned also in the post I am new to jQuery/JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.').click(function(){
    $('.round-details')
```

});

this is not correct. What's inside the brackets

```
$('here')
```

identifies your selector, which in case of click triggers an action.
You should put your target element selector inside that brackets, e.g.

```
$('.my-element-container .my-element div').click(function () {
    //your actions to be executed on click on the element
});
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense thanks Jumanji. I will have a play around and get back to you on how I go :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the CSS selector parser. `.` is an invalid selector (you have it in your `$('.')`). The `.` starts a [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html), but you have to have something after it, e.g.:

```
$('.some-class-here').click(function(){
    $('.round-details')
});
```

Or you may not want a class selector at all, in which case don't use `.`.

The reason you see the error in `jquery.js` is that it's jQuery that's calling the CSS selector parser for you. You call `$('.')` and it turns around and calls the browser's selector parser (or its built-in Sizzle, depending). In either case, since `.` is an invalid CSS selector, it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys,

I have found what the issue was and man am I embarrassed.

I was working on the page and thought that Dropbox had synced all the files, apparently not. I get to work and see why it worked on OS X and not Windows and immediately I was realised what was happening.

So sorry for wasting all of your time.

Stu

Comment: This post dates back, but in case you're still using Dropbox to sync files-- I highly recommend you switch to Git. I tried Dropbox to work on projects and it is a nightmare!